# Is stackoverflow the place for design questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

If I had a question about software design should it be asked on stackoverflow or somewhere else?

e.g. Should my software have a close button at the top or the bottom?

Comment: Have you seen this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/ ? I think that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user experience type questions there is [SE.UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Programming design questions are fine on StackOverflow itself. Do keep in mind though that your question should never be a poll type of question or simply seeking opinion, IOW "Should my window have a close button at the top or bottom?" is a little open ended. *Why* are you considering having it on the bottom, have you done any research to validate your thoughts either way?